# Kotlin regex split - removing trailing space

Tags: regex, kotlin

In Kotlin, I split a sentence into words. The `split` method adds an empty space a the end of the list, however. How to get rid of the trailing space?
Is there a simple way to do it without creating a new list?

```
package com.zetcode

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val text = "I saw a fox in the wood. The fox had red fur."

    val pattern = "\\W+".toRegex()

    val words = pattern.split(text)

    println(words)
}
```

The example prints `[I, saw, a, fox, in, the, wood, The, fox, had, red, fur, ]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The empty item appears there because your string has a non-word `.` char at the end. You may just omit empty items to solve the problem:

```
val text = "I saw a fox in the wood. The fox had red fur."
val pattern = """\W+""".toRegex()
val words = pattern.split(text).filter { it.isNotBlank() }
println(words) // => [I, saw, a, fox, in, the, wood, The, fox, had, red, fur]
```

Alternatively, use a matching approach with the opposite pattern, `\w+`:

```
val pattern = """\w+""".toRegex()
val words = pattern.findAll(text).map{it.value}.toList()
// => [I, saw, a, fox, in, the, wood, The, fox, had, red, fur]
```

Comment: The alternative approach is definitely the way to go regarding readability... it already reads like: "find all words" in contrast to "split by everything which isn't a word, filter out which isn't blank and call it 'words'" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the last item:

```
val words = pattern.split(text).dropLastWhile { it == "" }
```

Comment: Oh no, it is a bad idea because the last item is not always empty when using the `\W+` regex to split a string. It happened to be empty here because of the dot at the end.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew *The split method adds an empty space a the end of the list, however* this is the OP's question

Comment: If the text is `I saw a fox in the wood. The fox had red fur`, then `\W+` splitting [will result in a list that has no empty item at the end](http://rextester.com/FPOMU40120), and your code will remove `fur`. It is not that regex splitting always produces an empty trailing item.

Comment: I can't recommend this approach as well. It is rather a quick fix for that specific case, but will not work for other sentences as Wiktor already demonstrated. It's better to solve the actual problem then to use quick fixes.

Comment: @Roland I agree, but the question was not about proposing a new split method but for removing the last item without creating a new list

Comment: @Roland the problem is the last empty string if it exists, or not? The problem is solved by removing the last item if it is empty, or not?

Comment: @Roland at the beginning I took as a fact that everytime an empty string was added at the end. I did not question that. Since this is not the case I edited my answer and now it produces the result the OP wanted. If the OP prefers to modify the regex and some filtering it's his right to go that way. But don't tell me that filtering is recommendable and drop() is not.